# Which preposition goes better on the given statement?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Patricia, you will receive the Medicare Enrollment Worksheet **at/to** your mailing address 90 days prior from your eligibility date.

Which preposition goes better on the above statement?

Comment: NB: *prior **to***, not ***from***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**at**. It will be sent **to** the mailing address but it will be received **at** the mailbox.